# Python etree XMLPullParser to access text nodes

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to use Python's etree XMLPullParser to parse xml in a non-blocking fashion.
It does not report text-nodes as events; the docs state:
The supported events are the strings "start", "end", "comment", "pi", "start-ns" and "end-ns"
(https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLPullParser)

Rather, requires me to access text from Element events.
It appears I can only access the first text-node of any given Element.
Is XMLPullParser capable of accessing all text nodes in the xml?!
How can I get the code below to access the text-node "text3"?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# It seems "text3" cannot be accessed by the following code?!
xml = "<a>text1<b>text2</b>text3</a>"

# There is no "text" or "characters" event type.
# All we can access is start-element and end-element.
eventsToHandle = ["start", "end"]
parser = ET.XMLPullParser(eventsToHandle)

# There is no "text3" in the output.
parser.feed(xml)
for e, x in parser.read_events():
    print(e, f"<{x.tag}>", f"(text: {x.text})")
```

Output contains no "text3", nor can I think of any way to access that text-node:

```
start <a> (text: text1)
start <b> (text: text2)
end <b> (text: text2)
end <a> (text: text1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.itertext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.itertext) to iterate over all text nodes:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = "<a>text1<b>text2</b>text3</a>"

eventsToHandle = ["start", "end"]
parser = ET.XMLPullParser(eventsToHandle)

parser.feed(xml)

for e, x in parser.read_events():
    if x.tag == "a" and e == "start":
        print(list(x.itertext()))
```

Prints:

```
['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
```

Comment: Thank you; the "itertext" function solves this issue. This also led me to the "tail" function, which I can use to access text in a way that is aware of its place between siblings. Problem solved, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your print() like:

```
print(e, f"<{x.tag}>", f"(text: {x.text}, {x.tail})")
```

[Etree()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) knows element.tag, element.text, element.attrib and element.tail.

Output:

```
start <a> (text: text1, None)
start <b> (text: text2, text3)
end <b> (text: text2, text3)
end <a> (text: text1, None) `
```